# Setting xaxis values to %.2f on a bar graph

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a bar graph with multiple data series and i want to set the xaxis values to a significant value of %.2f I already tried using the set_major formatter for the first graph, but it resets the values to 0, while the values should be like the second graph.

How can I fix this?

[image: This bar graph]

My code look like this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.ticker as mtick

# select the measurement location
MATH = "import/data/place"
SAVE = "save/location"

fig, axes = plt.subplots(figsize=(12,15),nrows=2, ncols=1) # size of the plots and the placing
fig.subplots_adjust(hspace=0.5) # set space between plots

DATA = pd.read_csv(MATH,delimiter=',',usecols = [2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12],names = ['set_t','set_rh',
                   'type','math','ref','LUFFT','VPL','VPR','VVL','VVR','PRO'], parse_dates=True)
# select the data
temp = DATA.loc[(DATA['type']=='T')&(DATA['math']=='dif')] # dif temperature data
rh = DATA.loc[((DATA['type']=='RH')&(DATA['math']=='dif'))] # dif relative humidity data

# plot temperature
fg = temp.plot.bar(x='set_t',y = ['LUFFT','VPL','VPR','VVL','VVR','PRO'], 
                   color = ['b','firebrick','orange','forestgreen','darkturquoise','indigo'],
                   ax=axes[0])

fg.grid(True)
fg.set_ylabel('$ΔT$(°C)',fontsize = 12)
fg.set_xlabel('ref $T$ (°C)',fontsize = 12)
fg.set_title('Difference in T from reference at constant relative humidity 50%',fontsize = 15)
fg.yaxis.set_major_formatter(mtick.FormatStrFormatter('%.2f'))
fg.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mtick.FormatStrFormatter('%.2f'))

# plot relative humidity
df = rh.plot.bar(x='set_t',y = ['LUFFT','VPL','VPR','VVL','VVR','PRO'], 
                   color = ['b','firebrick','orange','forestgreen','darkturquoise','indigo'],
                   ax=axes[1])
df.grid(True)
df.set_ylabel('$ΔU$(%)',fontsize = 12)
df.set_xlabel('ref $T$ (°C)',fontsize = 12)
df.set_title('Difference in U from reference at constant relative humidity 50%',fontsize = 15)

plt.tight_layout()
plt.savefig(SAVE + "_example.jpg")
plt.show()
```

A sample of my data:

> 07:40:00,07:50:00,39.85716354999982,51.00504745588235,T,dif,,0.14283645000018197,-0.07502069285698099,-0.15716354999978677,0.0020201234696060055,-0.07111703837193772,-0.0620802166664447,
>
> 07:40:00,07:50:00,39.85716354999982,51.00504745588235,RH,dif,,-0.40504745588239643,3.994952544117652,2.994952544117652,4.994952544117652,,6.994952544117652,
>
> 08:40:00,08:50:00,34.861160704969016,51.1297401832298,T,dif,,0.22883929503095857,0.2509082605481865,-0.2575243413326831,0.24864321659958222,0.14092262836431502,-0.04441070496899613,
>
> 08:40:00,08:50:00,34.861160704969016,51.1297401832298,RH,dif,,-0.32974018322978793,3.8702598167702007,2.8702598167702007,4.870259816770201,,6.870259816770201,

Comment: Could you edit the question to include a small sample of values from your CSV, it would make it easier to reproduce your problem.

Comment: I have added it to the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is due to the fact that with a grouped barplot like this, made by Pandas, the x-axes loses its actual 'range', and the values associated with the tick position become the position itself. That's a bit cryptic, but you can see with `fg.get_xlim()` that the values have lost 'touch' with the original data, and are simply increasing integers. You can explore/debug the 'values' and 'positions' Matplotlib uses if you provide a `FuncFormatter` with a function like this:

```
def check_pos(val, pos):    
    print(val, pos)    
    return '%.2f' % val
```

This basically shows that no formatter is going to work for your case.

Luckily the `ticklabels` are set correctly (as text), so you could parse these to float, and format them as you wish.

Remove your formatter altogether, and set the xticklabels with:

```
fg.set_xticklabels(['%.2f' % float(x.get_text()) for x in fg.get_xticklabels()])
```

Note that Matplotlib itself is perfectly capable of preserving the correct `tickvalues` in combination with a bar plot, but you would have to do the 'grouping' etc yourself, so that's not very convenient as well.